# How to change specific row/line color in ListView android?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

i have a `ListView` with a `CustomAdapter` and i can change the clicked line's color.
But i need to change the color when the user ask for the answer (it's a quiz app), and i tried to set a public method to call it from my `MainActivity`, but i got a erro.

MyCustomAdapter code:

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item, null);
    lista = parent;
    holder.tv=(io.github.kexanie.library.MathView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.texto);
    holder.row=(RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.row);
    holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imagem);
    holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        holder.tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
    } else {
        holder.tv.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
    holder.tv.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    holder.tv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

    //Paint the clicked line, and remove color from the unclicked lines.

            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                parent.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundResource(R.color.branco);
                if (j != position) {
                    status[j] = false;
                }
            }

            if(!status[position]) {
                holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.azul);
                status[position] = true;
                respostas = ((MyApplication) simulado.getApplication()).getRespostas();
                mudarAlternativa(position);
            }else{
                holder.row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.branco);
                status[position] = false;
                mudarAlternativa(5);
            }

        }
    });
    return rowView;
}
```

To paint a line, i used `parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.color.mycolor);` and it works, but i want to paint it using a method:

```
   public void paintAnswer(int answerPosition){
   parent.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
   }
```

but i can't use `parent`, so i initialized `ViewGroup lista;` and set `lista` on `getView`. `lista = parent`. So i tried:

Public method on adapter:

```
   public void paintAnswer(int answerPosition){
   lista.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
   }
```

Calling from my MainActivity:

```
   adapter.paintAnswer(2);
```

and i got a erro.
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.ViewGroup.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference".

How can i reference `parent` outside `getView` to paint the lines using a public method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting views within `onClick`-listener, you bring the logic into the views themselves, this approach is not completely correct. It can make sense, but only to save resources, and not to update whole list. I also wouldn't rely on child postions of the `parent` to get a particular view, since the views for rows in `ListView` are reusable and the same view can represent different entitiy.

Instead, put this logic within the `getView` implementation, so the reusable views will not have to keep their state. An item should know its state, and say it to the view for it to adjust itself accordingly each time the view comes to the `getView`-method.

Comment: Thanks. i'm kind knew in this area, can you show me a little example ou a link, similar question, etc?

Comment: I tought about what you said, And I change the ListView To Five LinearLayout and it is much more EASY To manipulate.

Comment: @GLAPPsMobile, if you have a fixed number of views, it makes sense to use predefined set of views rather than `ListView`.

Comment: yes, i created a CustomList with 5 LinearLayouts and separators. And it's working pretty good. http://prnt.sc/f127yk